# iTunes Connect - in app purchases

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have added a new in app purchase for my app. I have uploaded the screenshot and the status is "Waiting for Review".

I have NOT submitted the binary yet as I wanted to do some testing once the purchase has been approved.

The in app purchase has been in the "Waiting for Review" state for about 2 weeks now.

Does this indicate a problem? Or has anyone experienced a wait as long as this for approval?

Cheers,

Comment: How do you think Apple are going to test if there's no binary?

Answer (score 2):

You can test the in app purchase without being approved. See the docs how. You should submit a screenshot when you want the in app purchase to be tested. This is, when your app is already submitted.